# How safe is it to use a Linksys WAP54G Access Point?

Tags: wifi, wpa2-psk

I have a Linksys WAP54G v1 device that I want to use to create a second WiFi network.

The device is configured for WPA2-Personal, AES encryption with a random 64 character paraphrase.  The firmware is version 3.04 (circa 2009).

What is the risk in using an older device with older firmware if the encryption WPA2 is known to be "good"?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean random *63* characters ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18006390/why-is-the-wpa2-psk-key-length-limited-to-63-characters

Comment: Will the access point also be your firewall?

Comment: Yes, that's correct 63 character password.  I noticed that after posting that the device won't take 64 characters in the password field.

Comment: This device does not have any firewall capabilities.  I would have to add another device upstream if I wanted firewall functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Linksys WAP54G has two listed [CVE security vulnerabilities](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-833/Linksys.html) that are rated 10/10 in severity.

[CVE-2010-1573](https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2010-1573/) and [CVE-2010-2261](https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2010-2261/).

The details say that versions 3.04.03 and earlier are vulnerable to both.

In the case of CVE-2010-2261, the presence of [hardcoded credentials](http://www.securityfocus.com/archive/1/archive/1/511733/100/0/threaded) would allow any attacker able to send and receive web traffic to access dedicated debug web pages that give a root shell.

As for CVE-2010-1573, the presence of hardcoded credentials allow any remote attacker to access the router, escalate privileges, and [gain complete control.](https://tools.cisco.com/security/center/viewAlert.x?alertId=20682)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.  I'm astounded that CVE-2010-157 allows an unauthenticated attacker unauthorized access to the device.  Thanks for the input, I'll look for a new access point.

Comment: @Rick Another thing to check: Is this one of the models that couldn't properly disable WPS? I know a lot of Linksys firmwares were pretty bad about that, when the WPS vulnerabilities were disclosed.